# How to hide magento Price tab from admin panel

Tags: magento

I made separate provision for setting Prices for Product in admin panel. Now I want to hide the default Price tab from Manage product section. How I do this? Where I need to change.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the attribute set in backend, select your attribute set, and then delete prices group from attribute set.